# How to get substring with T-sql built-in function

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

Suppose I have a string like "firstname lastname" stored in Mytable column Name.
then I want to attract firstname and lastname in SQL like

```
select FirstName = substring(Name, ..),  LastName=substring(Name, ...) from Mytable
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `charindex` to find the location of the space:

```
select FirstName = substring(Name, 1, charindex(' ', Name)),
       LastName = substring(Name, charindex(' ', Name) + 1, len(Name))
from MyTable
```

This is littered with assumptions, e.g. there's exactly one space (what if my name is Billy Bob Harris, or Madonna?)

Rather than do it the way you're asking though, you might be better off using PARSENAME (as another comment says!).

Comment: I think that should be `charindex(' ', Name)` instead of `charindex(Name, ' ')` & you can safely replace 4000 with `len(name)`

Comment: @Alex K.: I-d just leave it as 4000 or 8000. The LEN(NAME) is still too long because you start the substring some way in. Why add an extra function?

Comment: why do this substring+charindex mess when PARSENAME is much easier and flexible? see gbn's answer for how it works...

Answer (score 3):

Leverage [PARSENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx)?

```
SELECT
   PARSENAME(REPLACE(name, ' ', '.'), 2),
   PARSENAME(REPLACE(name, ' ', '.'), 1)
FROM
    MyTable;
```

**EDIT** working example:

```
DECLARE @MyTable table (name varchar(25))
INSERT @MyTable 
    SELECT 'Joe Smith' 
    UNION SELECT 'Bill Jones' 
    UNION SELECT 'Billy Bob Braxton' 
    UNION SELECT 'Mark'

SELECT
   PARSENAME(REPLACE(name, ' ', '.'), 2),
   PARSENAME(REPLACE(name, ' ', '.'), 1)
FROM
    @MyTable;
```

Output:

```
------ --------
Bill   Jones
Bob    Braxton
Joe    Smith
NULL   Mark    

(4 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: +1, yields same results as substring+charindex, but easier and most likely faster as well.  If you need more names just add `PARSENAME(REPLACE(name, ' ', '.'), n)` where `n` is the part you need.

Comment: @Alex K.: this always will bollix you anyway. Of course, should be separate fields. Of course again, names are a nightmare http://stackoverflow.com/q/4611967/27535 and http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/6736/630

Answer (score -1):

You can also think about splitting string using space as seperator and then use splitted items as firstname and lastname