# Concise way to get column text before an optional substring?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm looking for a concise way to get the leading text of a column prior to an optional marker, on SQL Server 2008 (so no `IIF`). I have an `nvarchar` column which may or may not have a marker at some point in the text, and I need to return either the full column value (if there's no marker) or the bit prior to the marker (if there is). (It's not my schema, and I can't change it.)

I see these choices:

1. Do it with `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING`, which is verbose and ugly (see below), or
2. Create a function to centralize and hide the ugliness, and use it (see below).

Is there a better, built-in option? And if so, what is it? (The answer to this question may well be "no.")

*(I thought [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7755624/157247) talking about `PARSENAME` might be an option, but because the marker is optional, it isn't really helpful, and doing that rather than creating a function seems a bit hacky to me anyway...)*

---

Example of Option #1:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX('{}', data, 1) = 0 THEN
            data
        ELSE
            SUBSTRING(data, 1, CHARINDEX('{}', data, 1) - 1)
    END AS trimmedData
FROM ...
```

*Cough. Hack.*

---

Example of Option #2

```
SELECT dbo.StrUntil(data, '{}') as trimmedData
FROM ...
```

...where `dbo.StrUntil` is something like:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'FN' AND name = 'StrUntil')
   exec('CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[StrUntil]() RETURNS INT AS BEGIN RETURN 0 END')
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[StrUntil](
@str    nvarchar(max),
@substr nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX(@substr, @str, 1) = 0 THEN
            @str
        ELSE
            SUBSTRING(@str, 1, CHARINDEX(@substr, @str, 1) - 1)
    END
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative would be to append the marker to the end of your column and use `charindex` on the concatenated value.

```
left(data, charindex(N'{}', data+N'{}')-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to put the definition in the code rather than hide it in a function.  One reason is performance of user defined functions -- although the performance has much improved since the early days of SQL Server.  Another reason is that the user defined function may make sense to you today, but it might not make sense to someone else in the future.  To understand the query then requires looking up the definition of the function.  (This is mitigated if you define a set of common functions across the code you are writing.)

If you need to do this often, then I would suggest one of two things.  First, create a view that contains `TrimmedData` as a column with whatever method you prefer to define it.

The other is to define the table with a computed column:

```
TrimmedData as (CASE when data like '%{}%' then left(data, charindex('{}', data)-1)
                     else data
                end)
```

In either of these cases, it will be available to the users of the "table" (or view).  This ensures that the definition of `TrimmedData` is always the same and is readily available.

As a note, it is an (unimportant) matter of preference to use `like` and `left()` instead of `charindex()` and `substr()`:

```
SELECT (CASE when data like '%{}%' then left(data, charindex('{}', data) - 1)
             else data
        end) as TrimmedData
FROM ...
```

I force myself to use `like` in this context to continually remind myself that it is highly optimized on many databases and often the best performing method for finding a substring.

Comment: +1 for the view idea (as I said, I can't change the table, so can't do the computed table column), and also for the point about hiding information in functions, although in general I'm a believer in centralizing that stuff (within reason) for maintainability and don't do it enough to worry about the learning curve. Of course, putting it in a view is much the same as putting it in a function, someone has to go look at the definition either way...